# CKEditor jquery doesn't update values

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I have some CKEditor textareas like this:

```
<textarea id="ckedittext" name="params[somenumber]"></textarea>
```

Then I execute Jquery code to update textareas value:

```
$('#ckedittext').each(function() {
    var name = $(this).attr('name');
    CKEDITOR.instances[name].updateElement();
});
```

But this code doesn't work! I have no idea how to fix this problem, please help me somebody.

Thanks

Comment: ids are singular, you can not have more than one element with the same id. Is that your problem or is your sample code just sample code.

Comment: @epascarello CKEditor doesn't support multiple instances with same ids?

Comment: No, the HTML spec does not support multiple elements with the same id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give your elements a common class and use a class selector.

```
<textarea id="ckedittext" class="editor" name="params[somenumber]"></textarea>
```

and

```
$('.editor').each(function() {
    var name = $(this).attr('name');
    CKEDITOR.instances[name].updateElement();
});
```